# Excel vba declaration within a href

Tags: excel, vba, href, declaration

I' m trying to put a declaration within a href but I can't get it to work.

```
Dim hyp as string
Hyp = activeworkbook.fullname

"<a href= hyp >Link to file</a>"
```

Thanks in advance,
Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub generateHTML()

    Dim hyp As String
    Dim html As String

    hyp = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    html = "<a href= " & hyp & " >Link to file</a>"

    Debug.Print html

End Sub
```

Comment: "<A HREF=""file://" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
                  """>Link to the file</A>" is the code I was looking for. Thanks Ricardo doe jou effort.